# not storing text data into java array using scanner

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, file-io

My code is just printing out the last number from the list I create in a different program.
I need help storing the data into an array so  I can sort it after.
edit: I need to take data from a file which is 'numbers.txt' and store it into an array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int numberArray = 0;
    int[] list = new int[16];

    File numbers = new File("numbers.txt");
    try (Scanner getText = new Scanner(numbers)) {
        while (getText.hasNext()) {
            numberArray = getText.nextInt();
            list[0] = numberArray;
        }
        getText.close();
    }
    System.out.println(numberArray);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + list[i];
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm also not supposed to use arrayList<>

Comment: You've got to increment the list index when putting things in it. You're only placing items in `list[0]`! Use the `numberArray` variable. Increment it inside the loop and use it as the list array index.

Comment: You also need a `catch` or `finally` block after your `try` block. Without it this code won't compile

Comment: @hagbear: I didn't mean for you to delete your answer, just add an explanation.

Comment: You mean in the while loop?

Comment: Inside your while loop, you keep adding a new number to the 0th spot in your array, leaving all the other spots blank. And no, don't use numberArray for this purpose if you're going to use it to hold the entered number.

Comment: `My code is just printing out the last number from the list` because you're printing `numberArray` which contains the last read number. And you don't need to call `getText.close();`. The `try-with-resources` statement does that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction in the code.

1.) Inside while loop, `list[0] = numberArray;`, will keep adding elements on the same `index 0`, so lat value will override. SO something like `list[i] = numberArray;` will work, and `increement i` inside `while loop`. Take care of `ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception` here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int numberArray = 0;
    int[] list = new int[16];

    File numbers = new File("numbers.txt");
    int i =0;

// Check for arrayIndexOutofBound Exception. SInce size is defined as 16

    try (Scanner getText = new Scanner(numbers)) {
        while (getText.hasNext()) {
            numberArray = getText.nextInt();
            list[i] = numberArray;
             i++;
        }
        getText.close();
    }
    System.out.println(numberArray);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + list[i];
    }
    System.out.println(list);
}
}
```

Comment: The body of the `while (getText.hasNext())` loop could be a one-liner: `list[i++] = numberArray = getText.nextInt();` :D.

Comment: @Tom yes we can make optimizations in the code, but OP is not asking about optimizing the code, it is about the functionality itself is not working.

Comment: @ankur-singhal thank you for showing me. Although I did as you did and when I print out the array, it only prints out the memory address I believe.

Comment: @odus yes this statement `System.out.println(list);` will do that, so iterate as you are doing just above and print `System.out.println(list[i]);`

Comment: @ankur-singhal ahh I knew that! thank you! how do I get as good as you?

Comment: @odus if it solves your purpose, pls accept/upvote the answer